# What should argon2id parameters be

Tags: hash, password-hashing, argon2

I plan to use it locally on mobile devices. These seems to do not offer computational power as good as on a server.

So what could be a secure argon2id parameters that run around 1s since offline apps should also be friendly too?

Comment: [Similar question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/84081/555). There are standard recommandations [there](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9106.html#name-parameter-choice) in RFC 9106

Comment: 3 iterations and 64 MiB of memory is a decent lower bound. That takes 0.07 seconds on my desktop using libsodium though, which is literally nothing. I wouldn't go below 3 iterations, and you likely can't use much more memory than that on mobile devices. You probably need to do benchmarks on the type of device you're using to try and find the best parameters.